# Bltoolkit Manage DbManager in repository pattern (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, repository-pattern, bltoolkit

I'm using bltoolkit in my ASP.Net application , I use repository pattern to manage my data access layer. foreach operation i open a new DbManager .  I cannot find a way to open and dispose the DbManager Object per request or session . any ideas

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, best way of usage:

```
    public IEnumerable<int> GetMyTableIds()
    {
        using (var dbManager = new DbManager("database"))
        {
            return dbManager.GetTable<MyTable>()
                     .Select(table => table.Id)
                     .ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Call of

```
new DbManager("database")
```

can be extracted to factory.

Or you may use thread static variables

```
static class DbManagerContainer
{
   [ThreadStatic]
   public static DbManager DbManager;
}

public void Request_Start()
{
   DbManagerContainer.DbManager = new DbManager("database");
}

public void Request_End()
{
   if (DbManagerContainer.DbManager == null)
   {
     //Write warn to log. This is not normal case.
   }
   else
   {
      DbManagerContainer.DbManager.Dispose();
      DbManagerContainer.DbManager = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: what i need exactly to open one DB manager per request which was made using HTTPContext items and on Request_Start event open a new DBManager then dispose it in Request_Event

Comment: Why do you need split open and dispose DBManager to different methods? Use DbManager in local context only.

Comment: Because I need one DBManager per request, my site get thousands of hits and each request make many trips to the DB so it is difficult to open a new DBManager with each operation. Another thing is that I use lazy loading with a one generic repository method which return generic queryable object so I need an open session, because if I'm using "using" keyword it will dispose the DBManager once i got out of the using scope so when i call queryable.ToList method it will find a disposed DB Manager

Comment: that is an alternative solution for this case but still my solution is recommended. using HTTPContext over ThreadStatic, you can see this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ATaleOfTwoTechniquesTheThreadStaticAttributeAndSystemWebHttpContextCurrentItems.aspx